# How to build a server/client protocol

Tags: java, sockets

Trying to understand how to create a protocol for my java sockets.

I'm writing the server code and I need to add a protocol to govern how the data communicates with the client. The concept is client sends a integer to server...server responds by sending back corresponding file line from text field.

What would you recomend I add in the protocol for this?

Comment: AJAX/JSON, simple web app for the beginning. You then have the standard infrastructure and can easily develop.

Comment: Its being done in Java. Its a module im doing in University

Comment: Yes I meant a Java web app. A protocol using text, XML (web service, remote procedure call) or JSON, seems most flexible. Efficiency, binary protocols makes only sense for mass data or a later phase.

Answer (score 0):

I would at least do the following:

Add a checksum to each package to make transmission-errors detectable. Add to response the number of the line . This way the client can make more  than one request at a time and can see in the responses to which request the line refers.

In general I would prefer to use an already established protocol, like the one used by a REST service. Creating your own protocol has always the danger that you overlooked some issues that may happen when the protocol is in use. Think is security and integrity is an issue for your application. If yes this must be build in the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google's [Protocol Buffer Language](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) it works in almost all common languages and the input file is language-neutral.